# Какой vps/vds подойдет для ratchet websockets php?

Tags: php, vps, vds, ratchet

Я что то не могу понять, точно ли подойдет vps, или vds?
И, я вроде смотрю, то установить php, mysql я смогу.
Но вот как туда загрузить сервер созданный с помощи Ratchet, и мне нужно еще установить ZeroMQ, который я мучался устанавливать на свой windows на php. Я не знаю как это сделать. Я знаю только что можно зайти на удаленный стол, windows, и там все установить. Но вот vds ubuntu, я только могу зайти в консоль.

Вообще я просто хочу вашего ответа, можно ли установить библиотеки с php и туда закинуть созданный сервер? Если нет то что мне нужно приобретать?
UPD: Пока что смотрю вариант vds, ubuntu

Comment: Вы хотите получить в одном ответе год+ опыта ?  Или в чем вопрос ? 

Вам нужно получить возможность  на свой сервер ставить то что вам нужно. Из того что вы написали, это vds.  (виртуальный выделенный сервер, где вы через консоль можете устанавливать то что вам нужно от суперпользователя). Вероятно это может быть и VPS в случае если администратор установит это расширение. 

Так же вам нужно иметь возможность запустить websocket процесс. Либо руками, либо через supervisor.

Ну или начинайте забывать про VPS VDS и говорите про контейнеры. Благо уже 2022 год на дворе.

Comment: @zalex извините если мой вопрос был плохо написан и был требовательным. Я просто был взамишательстве что делать и куда идти. Спасибо за ответ, буду пользоваться то что вы написали